# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] when I want to os.startfile() a .mkv file in Python

Tags: python

I have a project in python3 in which I have a movie database with title, plot, rating, genres... and when I click on the movie in the interface that open the movie file.

when I want to open a .mkv video file I got FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
For information I'm French and I have accents in the path name.

there is the code:

```
# coding=utf-8
import os

def openMovie(path:str):
    """
    correct file format due to os.getcwd(), and open a video file
    """
    correctPath = ""
    for letter in path:
        if letter == '/':
            correctPath += '\\'
        else:
            correctPath += letter
    
    print(correctPath)
    os.startfile(correctPath)
```

There is the complete error:

```
  File "c:\Users\nsaur\Mon Drive\travail_texte\Programmation_à_côté\MovieSearcher\movieOpener.py", line 16, in openMovie
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\nsaur\Desktop\Travail - Logiciels\Téléchargement_films\Telechargement_JDownloader\Lupin.the.3rd.The.Mystery.of.Mamo.1978.UHD.BluRay.2160p.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.HEVC.REMUX-FraMeSToR.mkv")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: 'C:\\Users\\nsaur\\Desktop\\Travail - Logiciels\\Téléchargement_films\\Telechargement_JDownloader\\Lupin.the.3rd.The.Mystery.of.Mamo.1978.UHD.BluRay.2160p.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.HEVC.REMUX-FraMeSToR.mkv'
```

The file name in my database:

```
C:/Users/nsaur/Desktop/Travail - Logiciels/T\xE9l\xE9chargement_films/Telechargement_JDownloader/Lupin.the.3rd.The.Mystery.of.Mamo.1978.UHD.BluRay.2160p.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.HEVC.REMUX-FraMeSToR.mkv
```

I saw somewhere that I have to put "# coding=utf-8" at the start but I'm not sure if this work or if the problem is somewhere else.

edit: when I print correctPath it gives me

```
 C:\Users\nsaur\Desktop\Travail - Logiciels\Téléchargement_films\Telechargement_JDownloader\Lupin.the.3rd.The.Mystery.of.Mamo.1978.UHD.BluRay.2160p.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.HEVC.REMUX-FraMeSToR.mkv
```

PROBLEM SOLVED: I used subfolders and I forgot to take the subfolder to complete the path.

Comment: There's no need to convert backslashes to forward slashes, by the way.  Forward slashes work just fine in Windows.

Comment: If you're getting `FileNotFoundError`, that strongly suggests that the file really doesn't exist.  Can you show us some output from a command window, executing a `DIR` command in that directory?

Comment: Does `dir C:\Users\nsaur\Desktop\Travail - Logiciels\Téléchargement_films\Telechargement_JDownloader\Lupin.the.3rd.The.Mystery.of.Mamo.1978.UHD.BluRay.2160p.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.HEVC.REMUX-FraMeSToR.mkv` on the command line work?

Comment: The traceback shows a hard-coded string, nothing from a database. It looks like your database was written using a Windows code page (the `\xE9` is `é`, and etc...). So, when you read the database, you'd want to decode with the same code page. `# coding=utf-8` can be put at the top of the .py file to declare its encoding, but utf-8 has been the default for .py files for a long time, so it would not  make a difference. This will likely be a problem with how this file path is read from the database.